# Why isn't this proof sufficient for showing that $L^\infty$ is a Banach space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Suppose we have already shown that $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is a norm. In order for $L^\infty$ to be a Banach space, if $\{f_n\} \subset L^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence such that $\| f_n - f\|_\infty \rightarrow 0$, then $f \in L^\infty$.

By the assumption of convergence, choose $N$ such that
$$\|f_n - f\| < \epsilon, \quad \forall n \geq N$$
and let $\|f_n\| = C$, where we know $C < \infty$ since $f_n \in L^\infty$. Then,
$$\|f\|_\infty \leq \|f_n - f\|_\infty + \|f_n\| \leq \epsilon + C < \infty \\
\implies f \in L^\infty$$
I know this proof is incorrect as I did not even use the fact that $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy. Also looking at other proofs (for example, this one: [$L^{\infty}$ is a Banach Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2198797/l-infty-is-a-banach-space)) I can see that I still have a lot to show.

I would like to know why the above proof fails, does it assume something that has to be shown or that is not correct?

Comment: Well, just compare what you have proved with the definition of completeness.  They are not the same.

Comment: What you showed is $L^\infty$ being closed. This is necessary to show but not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Cauchy sequence $(f_n)_n$, you should show that

1. There exists a function $f$ such that $(f_n)_n$ converges to $f$.
2. $f$ belongs to $L^\infty$.

You skipped step 1 by assuming from the start that $(f_n)_n$ converges to some $f$. This is something you have to show.

Comment: Thank you. So if I can show that $\{f_n\} \rightarrow f$, the proof will be complete?

Comment: @CBBAM - In your last comment, what's $f$?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Some function that $\{f_n\}$ converges to (not necessarily in $L^\infty$)

Comment: Okay. But you do realize that you have to come up with $f$, right? Your comment made it a bit unclear, and it's the coming up with $f$ where you have to do a lot of the work here. And you are not even allowed to assume that the $f_n$ converge to some not-necessarily-in-$L^\infty$ function.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Thank you I think I understand the problem now. As Will pointed out, I will first have to show that our assumption of Cauchy convergence implies convergence, and afterwards use my proof above to show that this $f$ is in $L^\infty$. Is that right?

Comment: @Will - Maybe re-write point 1 to say "That there exists some function $f$ such that ......". This whole post is based on the misunderstanding that they can assume an $f$ exists, so it might be worth driving that point home.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @CBBAM ", I will first have to show that our assumption of Cauchy convergence implies convergence..." Again, convergence to what? I honestly can't tell if you get the point or not. If your proof mentions $f$ before describing how it's defined, or what existence theorem you're using to show that it must exist, you'll be doing it wrong. Maybe go look at a proof of the completeness of $C[a,b]$ in the sup norm to see how they explicitly construct the limit function there.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Thank you I will take a look at that proof. When I said implies convergence, I meant we will have to construct an $f$ such that $f_n$ converges to it.

Comment: Excellent! Seeing you use the word "construct", instead of just "show", gives me confidence that you are on the right track. Good luck!

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Thank you for all your help and patience.