# Equivalence of convergence in $L^\infty$ and Caucy in $L^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite space. For measurable $f:\Omega \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$, define $\lVert f \rVert_\infty=\inf \{ K\ge 0 \mid \mu(|f|>K)=0 \} $.

I want to prove that, for $f, f_1,f_2,\dots \in L^\infty(\mu)$, the followings are equivalent:
(i) There is an $f\in L^\infty$ with $f_n \to f$ in $L^\infty$;
(ii) $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^\infty$.

The textbook (Klenke, 2nd ed, p.146) just says that this "is a simple consequence of the triangle inequality." But, I'm struggling to see how to prove this.

For example, for the direction (i)$\Rightarrow$ (ii), I tried to show $$\lVert f_{n}-f_{m}\rVert_{\infty}\le \lVert f_{n}-f\rVert_{\infty}+\lVert f_{m}-f\rVert_{\infty}.$$ Let $K_n=\lVert f_n-f \rVert_\infty$ and $K_m=\lVert f_m-f\rVert_\infty$. Then, it suffices to show that $\mu(|f_n - f_m|>K_n + K_m)=0$. From the triangle inequality, I know that $|f_n-f_m|\le |f-f_n| + |f-f_m|$, so I get $\mu(|f_{n}-f_{m}|>K_{n}+K_{m})\le\mu(|f_{n}-f|+|f_{m}-f|>K_{n}+K_{m})$. But I'm stuck here. I cannot decompose the RHS to $\mu(|f -f_n| > K_n) + \mu(|f-f_m|>K_m)$.

Similarly, for the other direction, I suppose I could use $|f_n-f|\le |f_n - f_N| + |f_m-f_N|$ for some large $N$, but I cannot translate to the triangle inequality in $\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty$.

Comment: Do you know that $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ is actually a norm. And as $f_{n}\to f$ in $L^{\infty}$, both $||f_{n}-f||_{\infty}$ and $||f_{m}-f||_{\infty}\to 0$ as $n,m\to\infty$ by definition of convergence in $L^{\infty}$. It's the other direction that I would be careful in approaching.

Comment: The thing is that the textbook introduces Minkowski a few pages later, so at this point the author avoids to use the triangle inequality for $\lVert\cdot\rVert_p$. I'm trying to prove the equivalent for $p=\infty$ using the triangle inequality for $|\cdot|$, which apparently the author has in mind.

Comment: I see. In that case, see that $\{|f_{n}-f|\leq K_{n}\}\cap \{f_{m}-f|\leq K_{m}\}\subseteq \{f_{n}-f_{m} \leq K_{n}+K_{m}\}$. Hence taking complements you have $\{|f_{n}-f_{m}|>K_{n}+K_{m}\}\subseteq \{|f_{n}-f|>K_{n}\}\cup \{f_{m}-f|> K_{m}\}$. Now use a union bound as both sets on the RHS have measure $0$.

Comment: In addition I suggest you look at this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2198797/l-infty-is-a-banach-space) . I hope my comment above and this link will suffice to answer your question.

Comment: Yes your answer and the linked post solved my question, thank you